# Inflating a layout in getView with inflator vs super.getView()

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

It seems that I have two ways to inflate a row layout in getView:
1)

```
convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

2)

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
```

Which of these is the right way to do it and why?